# GCD Proof Questions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am preparing for a discrete mathematics exam and am having trouble producing proofs for the following:

1. Prove that $\gcd (a,c)=1  \Rightarrow \gcd (a,b)= \gcd (a,bc)$
2. Prove that $\gcd \big( 2^s \pm 1, 2^t-1 )=2^{\gcd (s,t)-1}$

For (1) I am curious if the question should actually be asked as "iff" instead of in the current $a \Rightarrow b$ format.

For (2) Yeah...I have no idea here. None.

Comment: For (2) see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1).

Comment: The second statement is not true as it stands. The $-1$ should not be in the exponent on the RHS

Comment: Actually, The original version of this problem was exactly how the problem was given to us.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just do part 1 as part 2 has been done before [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

By definition $ \gcd(a,b)|a$  and $\gcd(a,b)|b \implies \gcd(a,b)|bc$

So $\gcd(a,b)| \gcd(a,bc)$

Now consider $\gcd(a,bc)|a$ and $\gcd(a,c)|1 \implies \gcd(ba,bc)|b  \implies \gcd(a,bc)|b$

So $\gcd(a,bc)| \gcd(a,b)$ and $\gcd(a,b)| \gcd(a,bc)$ so $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,bc)$

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ is not an "iff". Take $a=2$, $b=2$, $c=2$. $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,bc) = 2$ but $gcd(a,c) \neq 1$.

To solve $(1)$ you could show a stronger statement: the gcd is multiplicative. This question may help: [Multiplicative property of the GCD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163432/multiplicative-property-of-the-gcd)

Comment: Could you please explain how the argument would work.